# Shortcut for a specific example

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to move fives files from the `Documents` directory to another directory without writing every files explicitly. Is there a shortcut (e.g. using numbers) I could use?

I don't want to do something like this :

```
mv ./Documents/Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf ./Anotherdirectory
mv ./Documents/Lettre de motivation - Candidature Agent Soutien technique.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
mv ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_1.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
mv ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_2.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
mv ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_3.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
```

or

```
mv ./Documents/Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf ./Documents/Lettre de motivation - Candidature Agent Soutien technique.pdf ./Anotherdirectory ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_1.pdf ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_2.pdf ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_3.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
```

If I could associate a number (e.g. `mv ./Documents/1;2;3;4;5 ./Anotherdirecotry`) to each file and using only those numbers instead of the whole path each time it should be more convenient.

To solve my problem, all I need to know is how could I reference such files?

```
jeremie@jeremie-MacBookPro ~> ls ./Documents
Curriculum_Vitae/
Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf
Lettre de motivation - Candidature Agent Soutien technique.pdf
Lettre_de_reference_1.pdf
Lettre_de_reference_2.pdf
Lettre_de_reference_3.pdf
```

I thought I could reference a file in using the dollar sign. So I want want to access the file  `Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf`, I could use the command `ls ./Documents/$2`.

Comment: Cross-posted here http://askubuntu.com/questions/849576/is-there-exist-a-shortcut

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't have a lot of experience on this experience  despite my score. I'll remove my question on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: where does ./Documents/$2 come from? I don't think your question is clear.

Comment: Are they all PDFs? Do the filenames have anything in common with each other but not with any other file in the location?

Comment: Yes, all of them are pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Unix/Linux commands allow you
to specify multiple filenames in a single command. 
So, as long as you want all the files to go to the same destination,
you don’t need to use five separate commands; you can say

```
mv "./Documents/Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf" "./Documents/Lettre de motivation - Candidature Agent Soutien technique.pdf" ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_1.pdf ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_2.pdf ./Documents/Lettre_de_reference_3.pdf ./Anotherdirectory
```

Notes:

- Because multiple “words” in a command
  are typically treated as separate filenames,
  you must do something special to get the software to treat
  `./Documents/Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf` as a single file name
  and not three. 
  In fact, several characters are special
  and must be handled in a special way to use them as part of a file name —
  these include `&`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `|`, `\`, `;`,
  `'`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `?`, `!`, `$`, `` ` `` and sometimes `~`. 
  The simplest way to handle them is to enclose them in quotes:
  double quotes, as shown above, or single quotes:

  ```
  './Documents/Curriculum Vitae (Francais).pdf'
  ```

  (The rules get more complicated
  for some of the characters.) 
  Another way is to put a backslash (`\`)
  before each of the special characters;
  e.g.,

  ```
  ./Documents/Curriculum\ Vitae\ \(Francais\).pdf
  ```

  Most
  people find quoting to be more convenient.
- When you’re handling files (and directories) in the current directory,
  you generally don’t need to use `./`. 
  You (usually) need this when you’re *executing* a program
  in the current directory. 
  It can also be a useful trick to prevent a filename
  from beginning with dash (**`-`**). 
  It’s a normal character *inside* a filename
  (e.g., in `Lettre de motivation - Candidature Agent Soutien …`)
  but at the beginning it will be interpreted as an option. 
  Another way to handle filenames that begin with dash
  is to put a double dash (**`--`**) before the first filename;
  e.g.,

  ```
  mv [options] -- file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 target_directory
  ```

  but that doesn’t always work.

If you want to move *all* the `.pdf` files from the current directory
into the subdirectory, you can do

```
mv -- *.pdf Anotherdirectory
```

Note that you must *not* put the `*` in quotes here. 
This time you *want* to get the special meaning,
which is “all files matching this pattern.”

Some other tricks you can use
when several of the filenames are very similar include:

```
mv -- … Documents/Lettre_de_reference_?.pdf Anotherdirectory
```

and

```
mv -- … Documents/Lettre_de_reference_[123].pdf Anotherdirectory
```

and

```
mv -- … Documents/Lettre_de_reference_[1-3].pdf Anotherdirectory
```

and

```
mv -- … Documents/Lettre_de_reference_{1,2,3}.pdf Anotherdirectory
```

and

```
mv -- … Documents/Lettre_de_reference_{1..3}.pdf Anotherdirectory
```

Read the manual to see how these differ.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv ./Documents/file{1..5} ./Anotherdirectory
```

Comment: I put file1, ..., file5, but it is not the official names of my files. One of them is Lettre_de_reference, the other is Curiculum_Vitae and so on. Is it the same rule?

Comment: can you show some sample filename

Comment: how about this ?

mv Lettre*pdf ./Anotherdirectory

mv Curriculum*pdf  ./AnotherdirectoryXYZ

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is so specific, I suggest you create a function like this:

```
mymv(){ mv ./Documents/"$1" ./Anotherdirectory; }
```

`$1` represents the first parameter of the function here.

After defining the function, each time you want to move a file, use:

```
mymv FILE
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'd like something I could use pretty often. Roughly, all I need is a command that allows me to move many file in the same time, but with simplicity.

Comment: @SandraRoss you mean move a bunch of files in ./Documents, but not all files? if so, you'll need to explain your requirements in much more details.

Comment: Yes, a buch of files, but not all files